# Split a string in an array of strings in c

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am trying to split a string based on a given char, in this case `' '` and assign each word to an array of strings and print out each element of the array.

So far, I am able to get each word of the string except for the last one :(

How do I get the last word?

code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char    str[101] = "Hello my name is balou";
    char    temp[101];
    char    arr[10001][101];
    int     count;
    int     i;
    int     j;

    count = 0;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n')
        {
            strcpy(arr[count], temp);
            memset(temp, 0, 101);
            count += 1;
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
        temp[j] = str[i];
        i++;
        j++;

    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < count)
    {
        printf("arr[i]: %s\n", arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

output:

```
arr[i]: Hello
arr[i]: my
arr[i]: name
arr[i]: is
```

Comment: As for your problem, you need an extra `strcpy` call after the splitting loop to get the last part.

Comment: `memset(temp, 0, 101)` should also be called _before_  you enter the while loop. And BTW it should be `memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp))`, in case you change the size of `temp`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you do:

```
while (str[i] != '\0')
```

you won't do any `strcpy` of the last word.

You can add

```
strcpy(arr[count], temp);
count += 1;
```

**just after the `while`**

But...

Notice that your current code has a number of problems. For instance double spaces, strings ending with a space, strings starting with a space, etc.

Further do

```
char    temp[101];  -->   char    temp[101] = { 0 };
```

and also add some code to ensure that `j` never exceeds 100

and... the size of `char    arr[10001][101];` may be too big as a variable with automatic storage duration on some systems.

And

```
printf("arr[i]: %s\n", arr[i]); --> printf("arr[%d]: %s\n", i, arr[i]);
```

Comment: Awesome ^^ thx a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Research string token `strtok` function and accessing values pointed by array of pointers.
[strtok()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)
[array of pointers](https://dyclassroom.com/c/c-pointers-and-strings)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
  char str[80] = "Hello my name is balou";
  const char s[2] = " "; //delimiter
  char *token; 
  char *words[5]; //store words
  int i = 0;
  
  /* get the first token */
  token = strtok(str, s);
  
  /* walk through other tokens */
  while( token != NULL )
  {
    words[i++] = token;
   
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
  }
  
  int r, c;
  
  // print words
  for (r = 0; r < 5; r++)
  {
    c = 0;
    while(*(words[r] + c) != '\0')
    {
      printf("%c", *(words[r] + c));
      c++;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  
  return(0);
}
```

OUTPUT:
[image]